# Same purchaseToken in cordova-plugin-purchase

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm implementing cordova-plugin-purchase in app for Android, I have working all but I have a one thing to fix.

In my app when I make a purchase for subscription always get the same purchase token, in my first test this token was a valid but now when I unsubscribed and subscribed again in my app get the same purchasetoken.

When I put this purchaseToken in my iap server validator the status always is 0 and is logic because I made this purchase on 18th of January.

I need made something for https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase generate a new purchaseToken?

Always I get this in app when I subscribed:

```
    {
       "data": "{\"packageName\":\"com.rubeapp.padres\",\"productId\":\"premium\",\"purchaseTime\":1453157722465,\"purchaseState\":0,\"purchaseToken\":\"pdocnplgcbeoafhgimgkdmhj.AO-J1OxGqkmERQbgjQpcBZy6iaG8UCMzz-lHIYOc0fPwRFJLdAiVljZ31S-x904LUYFrUrQ-40qhIyGHRjIPhECB3e6VMIQukoVtbFLMrmsIpGfAmsImfjs\",\"autoRenewing\":false}",
       "signature":"jRTGPHwIX8WCspBMZGIk0PHEIFavKJ0NjXHh6MiHHOl4ZDtbAvHCXrKhP6j99fRtNzpynt5gxDsdI9schL4ed2G2pUJvVIwD/0Lf9p90gt/wuIaKrYxTe+A35i/4smafnYQTikhFv8F5c5/ckVL3ihdDwHLtd1ihOJpvF3z2t+vhNvFZ+f6ZRa2gWO5ucfLWvDV3rA/KK1PS3vXtW10NL+K73IbySXiFycqW8jK4N93eNnrifVGxgM1tkGv0nRSjqqZSD8Imb68LGb0GyPd1EOffMNgLHHEJ4iRR0+LN/ZgONK1dLxrGsmN+49OqJooyDKAWhCwMNCJGecuSc0ahaA=="
   }
```

And this is test response in my iap validator:

```
{"response":{"packageName":"com.rubeapp.padres","productId":"premium","purchaseTime":1453157722465,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"pdocnplgcbeoafhgimgkdmhj.AO-J1OxGqkmERQbgjQpcBZy6iaG8UCMzz-lHIYOc0fPwRFJLdAiVljZ31S-x904LUYFrUrQ-40qhIyGHRjIPhECB3e6VMIQukoVtbFLMrmsIpGfAmsImfjs","autoRenewing":false,"status":0,"service":"google"}}
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @jeko do you know what the issue is with the above question?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem is purchase have a time of life, while the suscription is live in playstore you get always the same purchasetoken.

In test you must wait the suscription expired to get a new purchasetoken.